# NodeJS - Missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js

I'm using the following library:

https://github.com/leftmostcat/passport-oauth2-password-grant

I'm trying to implement their example:

```
passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy({
    tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
    clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(refreshToken);
});
```

When running the application, I am getting the following error:

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Where is this issue coming from? I can't see there is an error in this code.

Comment: try to use linter such as eslint to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Syntax Error, missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing `passport.use(`

```
  passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy({
  tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
  clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
   console.log(refreshToken);
  }));
```